# Having trouble using Ajax with JSF on a Tomcat 7.0 server

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

I am a complete beginner when it comes to Ajax, and for some reason I cant get an easy example to work...

The javascript:

```
var xmlhttp;
function reloadIssues() 
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else 
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) 
        {
            document.getElementById("tester").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };


    xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.xhtml", true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

and the test xhtml page:

```
<div id="test">
    TEST TEXT
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="reloadIssues()">Change Content</button>
```

The JS file is called.

Ive tested it some and it seems that "xmlhttp.onreadystatechange" always is null and it never enters its function.

Is there something else then the code that can be the problem? Maybe on the tomcat server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element in question has an id of `test`

```
<div id="test">
```

yet you're locating it by `tester`

```
document.getElementById("tester")
```

Fix it accordingly.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, when going about ajax, I'd recommend adopting a decent framework instead of homegrowing one. I can warmly recommend [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for doing the ajax works. It's then as easy as:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#change').click(function() {
            $.get('test.xhtml', function(responseText) {
                $('#test').text(responseText);
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
    <div id="test">TEST TEXT</div>
    <button id="change">Change content</button>
</body>
```

Also, when using ajax in combination with a component based MVC framework like JSF, you've got to take *a lot* of things into account to keep client and server side state in sync. I wouldn't recommend homegrowing that either. Either upgrade to JSF 2.0 which ships with builtin ajax magic

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Change content" action="#{bean.change}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":test" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup id="test" layout="block">#{bean.text}</h:panelGroup>
```

with this method

```
public void change() {
    this.text = "new text";
}
```

or when you're still on JSF 1.x, then adopt an ajaxbased component library like RichFaces, IceFaces, PrimeFaces, etc.

Comment: The "test" and "tester" was an error while copy pasting.

I did not know that JSF had support for Ajax, I tried it out and it worked perfectly! I appreciate the help, thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible to use PrimeFaces for JSF 1.2 ? I thought it is only for JSF 2.0

Comment: @lkdg: PrimeFaces was the first component library which is from top to bottom designed with JSF 2.0 spec in mind. It's later backported for JSF 1.2. It's only not maintained anymore now. You can find them here: http://repository.prime.com.tr/org/primefaces/primefaces/1.1/